# If condition is skipped what is wrong with this code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class TimeFormat {

public static void main(String args[]) {
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter your Name.");
   String name=sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter the time format either it is AM or PM");
   String format=sc.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Enter hour time.");
   int hrs=sc.nextInt();
   System.out.print(":");
   int min=sc.nextInt();

    if(format.equals("PM")&&format.equals("pm")) {
        if(hrs>=12&&hrs<=5&&min>1) {
          System.out.println("Good afternoon "+name);
        }
        else if(hrs>=5&&hrs<=8) {
          System.out.println("Good evening "+name);
        }
        else if(hrs<=12&&hrs>=8&&min<59) {
          System.out.println("Goodnight "+name);
        }
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("Good Morning "+name);
     }
   }
}
```

Please command line always skip the if condition. I am new to java please help me.All is good but if statement have created the problem or so i think. Please how can i improve this code.

Comment: You have several if statements. Which one is skipped?

Comment: What numbers are >= 12 and <= 5?

Answer (score 5):

`format` can never be equal to both "pm" AND (`&&`) "PM". Either use OR (`||`), or, better yet, use :

```
if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("PM"))
```

which would cover "PM", "pm", "Pm" and "pM".

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if format is "PM" **or** "pm". You're checking **and**

```
if(format.equals("PM")||format.equals("pm"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Name.");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the time format either it is AM or PM");
        String format = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter hour time.");
        int hrs = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print(":");
        int min = sc.nextInt();

        if (format.equals("PM") || format.equals("AM")) {
            if (hrs >= 12 && hrs <= 5 && min > 1) {
                System.out.println("Good afternoon " + name);
            } else if (hrs >= 5 && hrs <= 8) {
                System.out.println("Good evening " + name);
            } else if (hrs <= 12 && hrs >= 8 && min < 59) {
                System.out.println("Goodnight " + name);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Good Morning " + name);
        }
    }
```

you had an && (AND) condition, you needed a || (OR) condition, + your choices are AM or PM, not PM or pm try comming from that